# How do I set the attribute of a hdf5 group in pandas / pytables?

Tags: python, attributes, metadata, hdf5, pytables

I am building a hdf5-file with different measurement datasets in it. For both, the experiment and each measurement I have some metadata I want to join.

My metadata consists of information about my samples, my setup, the test procedure and more, so that I would like to have it structured as nested dictionary. As the HDF5 file format is not able to store dictionaries in attributes (and I find the alternative to put the metadata in a dataset unclean), I decided to go with pyTables rather than h5py, because it has its own syntax to store/parse dictionaries as strings in/from the hdf5-attribute.

I built a file with the following structure

```
'G1'
    'M1'
    'M2'
```

I am able to store my metadata of each measurement doing the following:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(myHdfFile)
store.get_storer('G1/M1').attrs.myMetadataKey = myDict
```

But I am not able to do the same on my parent hdf-group / pyTable node. I tried the following:

```
store.get_storer('G1').attrs.myMetadataKey = myDict
```

and

```
store.get_node('G1').attrs.myMetadataKey = myDict
```

but none of them works. So how do I set the hdf-attribute of the hdf5 group?

Answer (score 1):

If found the answer in a pyTables tutorial:

Unlike for hdf5-datasets / pyTable leaves, one has to use ._v_attrs instead of attrs

```
store.get_node('G1')._v_attrs.myMetadataKey = myDict
```

to write metadata in the attributes of the group and inversely to read it out. The parsing of string to dictrionary is automatic if you write

```
myDict = store.get_node('G1')._v_attrs.myMetadataKey
```

You can also change the predefined group attributes like the title in this way. Just use 'TITLE' as 'myMetadataKey'.